# Why am I getting two different outputs in c when I use int or double?

Tags: c

So here is my code

```
  double blocksize = 32;
  double indexSize, tagSize, offsetSize;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   double index;
   double cachesize = 1;

   offsetSize = log(blocksize) / log(2.0);
   index = cachesize/blocksize * 1024;
   indexSize = (log(index) / log(2.0));
   tagSize = 32 - indexSize - offsetSize;


   printf("Offset : %f\n", offsetSize);
   printf("Index: %f\n", index);
   printf("Index  : %f\n", indexSize);
   printf("Tag    :  %f\n", tagSize);

   return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

So the problem is that when I assign everything to int, I get this output:

Offset : 5

Index: 0

Index  : -2147483648

Tag    :  -2147483621

However, when I assign everything as a double I get this output:

Offset : 5.000000

Index: 32.000000

Index  : 5.000000

Tag    :  22.000000

Why am I getting two different outputs?  I thought the only difference between a double and int is that int is a whole number but double is not a whole number.  It would return as an output similar to what I got 5.000000, 32.0000, ect.  So why am I getting two different outputs?

Comment: `a/b` with integers will also do integer division, i.e.   2/3 => 0.

Comment: When you use ints in arithmetic operations, the results are truncated to ints at each point.  For instance, `10/20*20` is `0`, but `10.0/20.0*20.0` is `10.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few differences between integers and doubles, but where your example is going wrong is on this line:

```
index = cachesize/blocksize * 1024;
```

When `cachesize` and `blocksize` are double, they are doing `double` division, which allows decimal places.

When `cachesize` and `blocksize` are integers, they are doing `integer` division, which truncates the decimals.

To fix your line of code you could convert one of the arguments to a `double` to force `double` division, like so:

```
index = ((double)cachesize / blocksize) * 1024;
```

Which will get you the results:

```
Offset : 5
Index  : 32
Index  : 5
Tag    : 22
```